# INSERT query - Null vs Empty String .. does it matter?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have the following code that inserts some data into an Access table. It starts with a comma delimited line that I split into a string array, then add the array elements as parameters:

```
string line = "one\ttwo\t\tfour";  

string[] values = line.Split('\t');  

using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [MyTable] (" +  
    "[Field1], [Field2], [Field3], [Field4] "  
    ") VALUES (" +  
    "?, ?, ?, ?" +  
    ")", con))  
{
    com.Parameters.Add("@p0", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = (object)values[0] ?? DBNull.Value;
    com.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = (object)values[1] ?? DBNull.Value;
    com.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = (object)values[2] ?? DBNull.Value;
    com.Parameters.Add("@p3", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = (object)values[3] ?? DBNull.Value;

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

In the above example, `@p2` will not have a value. It gets inserted into the Access table as a blank value, instead of a null value. At least I think I'm explaining that correctly. If I query for `Field3 is Null` I get no results. If I query for `Field3 = ""` I do get results. Does it matter if it's blank or null? Is there a 'preferred' option?

Thanks!

Comment: The precise term is a **zero-length string** or an **empty string**, not blank. Also, why are you using string concatenation to write the SQL instead of a multiline string?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Regarding concatenation vs multiline, I really don't have a good answer. But, after reading more about multiline strings just now, I'm going to start using those instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original statement:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = (object)values[2] ?? DBNull.Value;
```

From the description it is sending the empty string '' from `values[2]`, not the `DBNull.Value`. I would explicitly convert the empty string (or null) rather than using the null-coalescing operator (??):

```
com.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = String.IsNullOrEmpty(values[2]) ? DBNull.Value : values[2];
```

**Added**: As the type-specification (OleDbType.Char) is preventing this from sending DBNull to the database, I would revert to `AddWithValue`:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", String.IsNullOrEmpty(values[2]) ? DBNull.Value : values[2]);
```

This doesn't specify the type so should accept `DBNull` or the string. I prefer this approach anyway: if we specify the type we need to ensure that it is entirely consistent with the field data-type -> let C# work this out.

Comment: Just my opinion, but I would find the name `values` a little confusing when reading this code later, preferring something a little more descriptive.

Comment: I tried this, and get an error `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'String'`. And I agree about the `values` thing .. what started off as a simple little app quickly grew out of control. I plan to rewrite it all at some point.

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Andy, but I still get the conversion error when I try to run it. Specifically, the `DBNull.Value : values[3]` part.

Comment: This worked: `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", String.IsNullOrEmpty(values[2]) ? DBNull.Value : (object)values[2]);` and it inserted null values into the table instead of empty strings. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @JeffBrady. Casting to object is the only answer I've found that works.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `null` is definitely not the same as an empty string. So, yes, it matters. But only in your domain. So in other words, if the field isn't really nullable and Access is interpreting `DBNull.Value` as an empty string, then you just have to keep that in mind when looking for rows with no value. If the column were nullable in Access you wouldn't be seeing this behavior.

However, if the field in nullable, then I would recommend you actually just send in `null` instead of `DBNull.Value`. So, in other words:

```
values[0];
```

instead of:

```
(object)values[0] ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: I tried `values[2]` instead of `(object)values[2] ?? DBNull.Value` but I'm still getting an empty string inserted into Field3. When creating the table, I'm using `[Field3] Text(255) NULL` to create this particular field. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Correct me if I'm  wrong, but SQL NULL is not defined the same as .NET `null`, hence the `DBNull` type. If you get back `NULL` from MS SQL, comparing with .NET null may not compare correctly and `DBNull` corrects that. But, you can pass `null` into EF methods and EF will `do the right thing` with the value. In fact, this was the main motivation behind creating `struct Nullable<T>`, so you can use nullable ints and bools for nullable DB columns..